# Read Postfix E-Mails, edit and resend?

Tags: postfix

I have a postfix mail server (on example.com) and if I send a mail to alert@example.com I want to check the content of the mail, add some extra info and resend it somewhere else, (sms gateway email or so..)

Is something like that possible with postfix?
thanks.

Comment: Check out `procmail`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you couyld make alert@example.com an alias to a script,

you could put into */etc/alias* something like

```
alert@example.com:     "|/usr/local/myscript.pl"
```

and create a script that parses Standard input 
using:
MIME::Parser, Email::Simple and  your favourite perl modules...
or any other language of your choice...
The script could then email the result, call any sms web gateway, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you could do it with Postfix.  Essentially you want to put any messages to alert@example.com into a quarantine for processing which would be essentially putting it into the HOLD queue in postfix for processing.

There is probably a better lookup table to use, but, you could test with header_checks postfix file. /etc/postfix/header_checks  - You could make this check for TO: alert@example.com  and send to HOLD queue (note... there is probably faster/better lookup table for this)

If you read the comments in the header_checks file for HOLD it says...

```
#               Arrange  for  the  message to be placed on the hold
#               queue, and inspect the next input line.   The  mes-
#               sage  remains  on hold until someone either deletes
#               it or releases it for delivery.
...
#               Mail that is placed on hold can  be  examined  with
#               the  postcat(1)  command,  and  can be destroyed or
#               released with the postsuper(1) command.
# 
#               Note: use "postsuper -r" to release mail  that  was
#               kept  on  hold for a significant fraction of $maxi-
#               mal_queue_lifetime  or  $bounce_queue_lifetime,  or
#               longer.
```

Would mean logging in and manually checking the emails in the hold queue by command line, but, pretty much what you want?